# why chef-metal-ssh is failed

Tags: ssh, chef-infra

I was trying to follow https://github.com/double-z/chef-metal-ssh
I'm running the code below, it throws the exception:
[2015-01-19T06:03:39-06:00] ERROR: machineone had an error: ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 0)

```
require 'chef_metal_ssh'

name = "one"

with_ssh_cluster("~/metal_ssh")

machine name do
 action [:ready, :converge]
 machine_options 'ip_address' => '10.62.56.209',
 'ssh_options' => {
 'user' => 'root',
 'keys' => ['/home/chefuser/test.rsa']
}
files '/remote/path.txt' => { :content => 'foo' }
end

 machine_execute name do
    command "pwd" # this uses new_daemon_key to register with halo
 end
```

I want to know what's wrong of this code. And I don't understand for with_ssh_cluster("~/metal_ssh") what content should be in "~/metal_ssh"?  thanks.

Comment: You call this "your" code, but the questions you ask suggest that not only did you not write or understand this recipe, but that you may be lacking in basic Unix skills if you don't even know how to view a file in your home directory.

Comment: My previous description is not clear, sorry for that. Now I've updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that the issue is I was using chef 12.0.3, and in line 109 of /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/chef-12.0.3/lib/chef/dsl/recipe.rb

```
 resource.load_prior_resource(type, name)
```

But in chef-metal-ssh-0.1.2/lib/chef/resource/ssh_cluster.rb:18

it's defined as

```
 def load_prior_resource
   Chef::Log.debug("Overloading #{resource_name}.load_prior_resource with NOOP")
 end
```

so it throws

ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 0)

Answer (score 0):

I had to dig a little with the code to understand (I'm not using it).

According to the comment below found [here](https://github.com/double-z/chef-metal-ssh/blob/master/lib/chef_metal_ssh/ssh_driver.rb)

> # cluster_path - path to the directory containing the vagrant files,
>    # which should have been created with the vagrant_cluster resource.

The "~/metal_ssh" file should be the Vagrantfile path.

chaf-metal-ssh is a driver for chef-metal, I'm not sure you're comfortable with chef-metal, so I would advise starting by reading [This](https://docs.chef.io/provisioning.html#machine) and [This](https://github.com/opscode/chef-provisioning/blob/master/docs/configuration.md)

Comment: I thought it's RAW ssh which is with a list of already-provisioned servers. But looks like it depends on vargrant.

Comment: It's the .vagrant folder aside the Vagrantfile in which the provisionned boxes informations are stored (nothing RAW ssh here)... as it's an hidden folder, I said it is the path of the vagrantfile for ease of localisation.

Comment: I am not able to find the RAW ssh driver for chef-metal, is there a RAW ssh driver? thanks very much.

Comment: No the ssh driver is this one, take some time to read about chef-meal and how it is designed, maybe it's not the tool for what you try to accomplish ...